# How to allow class method overwrite with Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, class

I have a class `Animal` with some methods, and an extension of the class - called `Bird` - that overwrites one of its parent methods to handle an edgecase.

It looks like this:

```js
class Animal {
  constructor(animal) {
    this.animal = animal;
  }
  public define(){
    return {name: this.animal.name}
  }
}

class Bird extends Animal{
  public define(){
    return {color: this.animal.color}
  }
}
```

Calling `bird.define()` works fine. But Typescript goes mad, claiming:

> Property 'define' in type 'Bird' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Animal'.
> Type '() => { color: string; }' is not assignable to type '() => { name: string }'.
> Type '{ color: string; }' is missing the following properties from type '{ name: string; }':
> name

How to fix this except doing a `ts-ignore`?

Comment: This is intentional; a `Bird` is not an `Animal` if its `define` method returns something different. You will just have to rethink your software architecture a bit to determine what works best for you. Perhaps class hierarchies / `extends` are not needed here, and you can use some other form of JavaScript inheritance such as augmentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have a workaround:

```js
type AnimalObj = {
    name: string;
    color: string
}
class Animal {
    constructor(public animal: AnimalObj) {
        this.animal = animal;
    }
    public define(): Partial<AnimalObj> {
        return { name: this.animal.name }
    }
}

class Bird extends Animal {
    public define() {
        return { color: this.animal.color }
    }
}
```

There is no need to use `ts-ignore` in this particular case